# Java JLabel array remove element after use

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, jlabel

So I have a JFrame in Netbeans that holds 20 labels of math equations.

`mathLabel1` is "2 + 2"

`mathLabel2` is "4 * 4"

etc...

and if mathLabel1 is shown and the user guesses the right answer (4) then I want to `setVisible(false)` and remove that element from my array, so it doesn't come up as a question again.

Basically, no repeats.

Here is a short version of my code:

```
//declare variables
String strUserAnswer;
int i;
Random r = new Random();
int randvalue = r.nextInt(19);
JLabel[] math = {mathLabel1, mathLabel2, mathLabel3, mathLabel4, mathLabel5, mathLabel6, mathLabel7, mathLabel8, mathLabel9, mathLabel10, 
    mathLabel11, mathLabel12, mathLabel13, mathLabel14, mathLabel15, mathLabel16, mathLabel17, mathLabel18, mathLabel19, mathLabel20}; 
JLabel test;    

//method that chooses random math equation
public void random(JLabel test) {
    r = new Random();
    randvalue = r.nextInt(19);
    test = math[randvalue];

    if (test == math[0]) {
        mathLabel1.setVisible(true);
    }
    else if (test == math[1]){
        mathLabel2.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[2]){
        mathLabel3.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[3]){
        mathLabel4.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[4]){
        mathLabel5.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[5]){
        mathLabel6.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[6]){
        mathLabel7.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[7]){
        mathLabel8.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[8]){
        mathLabel9.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[9]){
        mathLabel10.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[10]){
        mathLabel11.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[11]){
        mathLabel12.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[12]){
        mathLabel13.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[13]){
        mathLabel14.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[14]){
        mathLabel15.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[15]){
        mathLabel16.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[16]){
        mathLabel17.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[17]){
        mathLabel18.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[18]){
        mathLabel19.setVisible (true);
    }
    else if (test == math[19]){
        mathLabel20.setVisible (true);
}
}                                          

private void guessButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // User clicks guess to enter answer, if correct part of puzzle appears

    strUserAnswer = answerText.getText();
    test = math[randvalue];

    //if the math equation chosen is 2+2...
    if (test == math[0]) {

        //show math equation
        mathLabel1.setVisible(true);

        //if answer is right...
        if (strUserAnswer.equals("4")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yay!! That is right!");
            //show puzzle piece, hide equation, and choose a new one
            label1.setVisible(true);
            mathLabel1.setVisible(false);
            //test.remove(math[0]);
            test = math[randvalue];
            answerText.setText(null);
            random(test);

        //if answer is wrong...
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Sorry, try again!");
            answerText.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

and that's repeated for `math[1]`, `math[2]`, `math[3]`, etc...

So how would I do this? I tried the remove() method but that was a shot in the dark...

Comment: Oh dear God please change that code design!!

Comment: I would create a `Question` class which could have a JLabel as property, although it's probably better to always use the same JLabel and set the text depending on the Question object. The Question object includes the question itself and the correct answer for it. Then you can have an ArrayList of Question objects.

Comment: I think setText would be a much better idea, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so this might make your day or break your heart, but you are doing way more than you need to with your random() method.  first off, it doesn't seem like you need to take in a parameter
because it looks like you are manually changing the value before you ever use it.  also, because each value in the array is in fact a JLabel, you can just say     math[randValue].setVisible(true) instead of going through the whole if statement thing.  and to solve your problem of removing stuff, there is a quick and dirty way you can do it that i will show you, but you are better off using an ArrayList instead of an Array.

```
public void random() {
  Random r = new Random();
  randValue = r.nextInt(math.length);  //make sure the index is always within the array
  JLabel[] temp = new JLabel[math.length - 1];  //this will do the trick
  math[randValue].setVisible(true);
  for (int i = 0; i < randvalue; i++) {
    temp[i] = math[i];  //fill the new array up to the chosen label
  }
  for (int i = randValue; i < temp.length; i++) {
    temp[i] = math[i + 1];  //fill the rest, omitting the chosen label
  }
  math = new JLabel[temp.length];  //math is now shorter
  math = temp;  //put everything back in the original array
}
```

this should work as a solution using arrays.
hope it helps.

Comment: In theory this should work, but it replaces it everytime I click the button, I only want it to change when you click the 'go' button and the answer is correct

Comment: in that case, just add an if statement to check if the answer is correct.  you may need/want to make a boolean variable to keep track of it.  You can also separate the code to remove the JLabel from the list into its own method: remove(int index) would be a good option.  That way, you can always pull up the right label, and if the button is pressed and the answer is correct, you call the remove method and everyone is happy.

Comment: +1 for the comment about the Random thing. -1 for the dirty Array solution. So in total +/- 0.

Answer (score 1):

If your data structure will constantly be changing, try using a List instead of an Array:

```
List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
int numLabels = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < numLabels; i++) {
    labels.add(new JLabel(i + " " + i));
}
```

From there you could always call:

```
labels.get(4).setVisible(false);
```

or

```
labels.remove(4);
```

And then revalidate your JPanel.

EDIT 2:

I may have misunderstood your question - it seems you want to remove a number and never create a label for it again. This is the correct way to do it:

```
int numIntegers = 20;
Set<Integer> possibleNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < numIntegers; i++) {
    possibleNumbers.add(i);
}
```

When you want to remove an item, use:

```
possibleNumbers.remove(14);
```

Then when you want to present this data, you can use:

```
panel.clear();
for (Integer number : possibleNumbers) {
    panel.add(new JLabel(number + "  " + number));
}
```

(Please note I was incorrect calling JLabels data - they are part of the presentation.)

Comment: So would `labels.remove(4)` remove that label from ever appearing ever again?

Comment: You have to understand the difference between your data and its presentation.

Your process is basically data -> presentation -> data -> presentation, ad infinitum. Once you change the data (for example, with labels.remove(4)), you still have to "present" the data. So you'll have to clear your JPanel and re-draw the JLabels again.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, I've changed my answer.

Comment: sdasdadas, is there any possible way I can do this without diverting away too much from the code I already have? This is the only part that doesn't work. And I never did understand Lists fully, nor did I understand the for loop in the way you did in your edit.

Comment: Not really, because of two things: your code doesn't run for more than one question (which means you'll be implementing that anyway), and it's very hard to look at your code as it is.

Whenever you have a ton of if statements, find a way to use a for loop. And my for loop isn't anything complex, it simply iterates through each item in the set. You can probably write the program in half the number of lines you have in the original question but you have to start with the basics - get a loop going where you are repeatedly asked questions. Then add JLabels.

Comment: I realize it's hard to look at and I apologize ':) I'll continue to work on it but you have put me on the right track for now. Thanks!

Comment: Sure - to answer the initial question: use an ArrayList or a Set (a Set won't allow duplicates).